# Unreal Engine Blueprint Map Variable is passed by value instead of reference

Tags: unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5, unreal-blueprint

After adding the beers, the two item maps are different. Which is the reason why this is pass by value instead of reference. I also tried using the Set By-Ref Var Node, but it still didn't work.

[image: After adding the item, the two item maps are different]

Comment: I don't understand what your problem is here. Could you please clarify what you mean?

Comment: The 'set' node will inevitably pass by value, because a TMap member exists in your class, not a pointer to a TMap member.

Comment: And how to i make a pointer to a map in blueprints?